# What does builder do that python code doesn't?

Tags: python, kivy, qr-code, barcode, kivy-language

When I use builder, the program outputs information from qr codes to the lower half of the application, but it is necessary to replace the built code with an equivalent python code, immediately information about qr codes ceases to be output

With builder:
`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy_garden.zbarcam import ZBarCam

DEMO_APP_KV_LANG = """

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ZBarCam:
        id: zbarcam
    Label:
        text: ', '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in zbarcam.symbols])
"""

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(DEMO_APP_KV_LANG)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

`With python code:`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy_garden.zbarcam import ZBarCam


class Demo(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.zbarcam= ZBarCam()
        self.add_widget(self.zbarcam)
        self.add_widget(Label(text=', '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in self.zbarcam.symbols])))



class DemoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Demo()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The `kivy`  language sets up bindings for you that the pure python does not. So your line in the `kv`:

```
text: ', '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in zbarcam.symbols])
```

sets up binding to `zbarcam.symbols` so that the `text` is updated whenever `zbarcam.symbols` changes.

And in the python code:

```
text=', '.join([str(symbol.data) for symbol in self.zbarcam.symbols]
```

sets the `text` once when that line is executed, and it is never updated.

Why must you replace the the `kivy` language code?